# Pivot rows into multiple columns

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, linked-server, pivot

I have a SQL Server instance that has a linked server to an Oracle server. There is a table on the Oracle server called `PersonOptions` which contains the following data:

```
╔══════════╦══════════╗
║ PersonID ║ OptionID ║
╠══════════╬══════════╣
║        1 ║ A        ║
║        1 ║ B        ║
║        2 ║ C        ║
║        3 ║ B        ║
║        4 ║ A        ║
║        4 ║ C        ║
╚══════════╩══════════╝
```

I need to pivot that data so the results are:

```
╔══════════╦═════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ PersonID ║ OptionA ║ Option B ║ Option C ║
╠══════════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║        1 ║       1 ║        1 ║          ║
║        2 ║         ║          ║        1 ║
║        3 ║         ║        1 ║          ║
║        4 ║       1 ║          ║        1 ║
╚══════════╩═════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a few ways that you can perform this data transformation. You have access to the `PIVOT` function then that will be the easiest, but if not then you can use an aggregate function and a `CASE`.

**Aggregate /Case version:**

```
select personid,
  max(case when optionid = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) OptionA,
  max(case when optionid = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) OptionB,
  max(case when optionid = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) OptionC
from PersonOptions
group by personid
order by personid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff4f8/8)

**Static Pivot:**

```
select *
from
(
  select personid, optionid
  from PersonOptions
) src
pivot
(
  count(optionid)
  for optionid in ('A' as OptionA, 'B' OptionB, 'C' OptionC)
) piv
order by personid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f7a3a/2)

**Dynamic Version:**

The two versions above work great if you have a known number of values, but if your values are unknown, then you will want to implement dynamic sql and in Oracle you can use a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure dynamic_pivot_po(p_cursor in out sys_refcursor)
as
    sql_query varchar2(1000) := 'select personid ';

    begin
        for x in (select distinct OptionID from PersonOptions order by 1)
        loop
            sql_query := sql_query ||
                ' , min(case when OptionID = '''||x.OptionID||''' then 1 else null end) as Option_'||x.OptionID;

                dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
        end loop;

        sql_query := sql_query || ' from PersonOptions group by personid order by personid';
        dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);

        open p_cursor for sql_query;
    end;
/
```

Then you return the results, you will use:

```
variable x refcursor
exec dynamic_pivot_po(:x)
print x
```

The results are the same with all versions:

```
| PERSONID | OPTIONA | OPTIONB | OPTIONC |
------------------------------------------
|        1 |       1 |       1 |       0 |
|        2 |       0 |       0 |       1 |
|        3 |       0 |       1 |       0 |
|        4 |       1 |       0 |       1 |
```

Answer (score 10):

This would be the equivalent in SQL Server syntax. Based on my reading of the Oracle docs, [NULLIF](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions102.htm) and [PIVOT](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php) appear to have the same format as their SQL Server kin. The challenge will be the pivot list which needs to be static unless you make the query dynamic as Itzik [demonstrates](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/dynamic-pivoting) but I have no idea if that can be translated to P/SQL

```
WITH PersonOptions(PersonID, OptionId) AS
(
    SELECT 1, 'A'
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'B'
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'C'
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'B'
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'A'
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'C'
)
SELECT
    P.PersonId
,   NULLIF(P.A, 0) AS OptionA
,   NULLIF(P.B, 0) AS OptionB
,   NULLIF(P.C, 0) AS OptionC
FROM
    PersonOptions  PO
    PIVOT 
    (
        COUNT(PO.OptionId)
        FOR OPtionId IN (A, B, C)
    )  P;
```

Answer (score 6):

I prefer to pivot query manually, but you may use `PIVOT` as well.

```
SELECT PersonID,
MAX(CASE WHEN OptionId ='A' THEN 1 END) AS OptionA,
MAX(CASE WHEN OptionId ='B' THEN 1 END) AS OptionB, 
MAX(CASE WHEN OptionId ='C' THEN 1 END) AS OptionC
FROM PersonOptions
GROUP BY PersonID
```

Comment: I myself think that `PIVOT` syntax is more convoluted compared to approach I use. However, I'm aware both of them give the same result, and I agree other people may think opposite.