# How to execute this procedure in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle-11g, plsql, pivot, dynamic-sql, cursors

I have this table in the below format:

```
Persnbr | Userfieldcd | Value
01      | Port | Funds   
01      | Vip1 | Systems  
02      | Port | Bank  
02      | Vip1 | Authority
```

This is how I want it:

```
Persnbr | Port  | Vip1
01      | Funds | Systems   
02      | Bank  | Authority
```

As I dont know the all the fields in the userfieldcd column, I am trying to dynamically pivot the table. So I am using this procedure but I dont know how to call it in PL/SQL developer. I am using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure dynamic_pivot_po(p_cursor in out sys_refcursor)
as
sql_query varchar2(1000) := 'select persnbr ';

begin
    for x in (select distinct userfieldcd from persuserfield order by 1)
    loop
        sql_query := sql_query ||
            ' , min(case when userfieldcd = '''||x.userfieldcd||''' then value else null end) as '||x.userfieldcd;

            dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
    end loop;

    sql_query := sql_query || ' from persuserfield group by persnbr order by persnbr';
    dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);

    open p_cursor for sql_query;
end;
/
```

When I call the procedure using:

```
VARIABLE x REFCURSOR  
BEGIN  
       dynamic_pivot_po(:x)  
    END  
    /
```

it gives me

> ORA-00900: Invalid SQL statement.

Comment: Would you like to actually tell us what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Jacobm001 sorry about that! I have adited my question!

Comment: Oracle 11 and higher has a built in 'PIVOT', see one of Tim Hall's excellent summaries: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php

Comment: @Jacobm001 the reason I am trying to do this dynamically is because the fields in the "userfieldcd" column are not consistent and tend to change.

Comment: @Rafeyiftikhar See [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30125/9003) on executing the procedure

Comment: @bluefeet thank you! But when I run: variable x refcursor
exec dynamic_pivot_po(:x)
print x, it gives  me ORA-00900 Invalid sql statement. why is that?

Comment: @Rafeyiftikhar Did you try the exact code that is in the other answer?  The code you posted above to execute is different.

Comment: @bluefeet yes I used the exact code from the other answer. I just updated this question. I am using PL/SQL developer 7.1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with PIVOT operator, but it require hardcoding all the pivoting values.

```
select * from (select Persnbr, Userfieldcd, value from pivot_test) pivot (max(value) for Userfieldcd in ('Port', 'Vip1'));
```

Building the query dynamically as your example:

```
declare
    in_clause varchar2(256);
    sel_query varchar2(256);
    n number := 0;
begin
    for x in (select distinct userfieldcd from persuserfield)
    loop    
        if n <> 0 then 
                in_clause := in_clause || ', ';
        end if;
        in_clause := in_clause ||  '''' || x.userfieldcd || '''';
        n := 1;    
    end loop;
    sel_query := 'select * from (select Persnbr, userfieldcd, value from persuserfield) pivot (max(value) for userfieldcd in ('||in_clause||'));';
    dbms_output.put_line (sel_query);
end;
/
```

Comment: the reason why I dont want to do this is because I dont know all the pivoting values and they are always being updated.

Comment: I've edited the answer to do a similar procedure as yours with `PIVOT` operator
 
An alternative is to use operator PIVOT XML which allows you to use the wildcard ANY, but it will return a formatted XML result

Comment: thank you for this!! but when I try to run this it gives me: ORA-01008: not all variables bound. Why do you think that is?

Comment: Check the code after you copy/paste/edited it. Check all variables. Maybe you are renaming a variable, but didn't rename it in every line.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a semicolon:

```
VARIABLE x REFCURSOR  
BEGIN  
   dynamic_pivot_po(:x); -- here
END; -- and here
/
```