# How to use PIVOT or LISTAGG to solve this?

Tags: oracle, query, plsql, pivot, listagg

I have a table like below.

| USERID | USERNAME | ITEM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | JESSE | ITEM1 |
| 12345 | JESSE | ITEM3 |
| 12345 | DON | ITEM2 |
| 12346 | DANNY | ITEM4 |
| 12346 | ELISA | ITEM1 |
| 12347 | ANDY | ITEM2 |
| 12347 | ANDY | ITEM4 |

What im trying to achieve is.

| USERID | USERNAME | ITEMS1 | ITEMS2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | JESSE | ITEM1 | ITEM3 |
| 12345 | DON | ITEM2 |  |
| 12346 | DANNY | ITEM4 |  |
| 12346 | ELISA | ITEM1 |  |
| 12347 | ANDY | ITEM2 | ITEM4 |

I've tried to use LISTAGG but cant get resuls like above. Or should i use something else?

Thanks!

Eliza

**Edit:** with SQLFiddle i tried with this but end up with error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fb69a/45/0

**Edit:** Found similiar dynamic pivot examples, but still cant get this working :/
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4471013000346257238
SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/51d2d/20/0

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1

(IDENT varchar2(10), USERNAME varchar2(10), ITEMNAME varchar2(10))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 (IDENT,USERNAME,ITEMNAME)
         VALUES ('12345','JESSE','ITEM1')
    INTO Table1 (IDENT,USERNAME,ITEMNAME)
         VALUES ('12345','JESSE','ITEM3')
    INTO Table1 (IDENT,USERNAME,ITEMNAME)
         VALUES ('12346','DON','ITEM2')
    INTO Table1 (IDENT,USERNAME,ITEMNAME)
         VALUES ('12346','DANNY','ITEM4')
    INTO Table1 (IDENT,USERNAME,ITEMNAME)
         VALUES ('12347','ELISA','ITEM1')
    INTO Table1 (IDENT,USERNAME,ITEMNAME)
         VALUES ('12347','ANDY','ITEM2')
    INTO Table1 (IDENT,USERNAME,ITEMNAME)
         VALUES ('12347','ANDY','ITEM4')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

Code:

```
create or replace procedure
get_data(p_x out sys_refcursor)
as
    l_query varchar2(400) :='IDENT';
    begin
        for x in (select distinct USERNAME from Table1 order by 1)
        loop
            l_query := l_query ||replace(', sum(decode(USERNAME,''$X'',ITEMNAME)) as $X '
         ,'$X',x.USERNAME );
        end loop;
    l_query := l_query ||' from Table1 group by IDENT ';
    open p_x for l_query;
end;
/

exec get_data(:x);
print x;
```

Comment: The term you're looking for is "pivot".

Comment: Ahh ok ill try to get more information about pivot then. This is all new to me :)

Comment: I cant figure out how to solve this with pivot either, because i don't know any values in that table besides their column names (USERID,USERNAME,ITEMS). Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pivot rows into multiple columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30119/pivot-rows-into-multiple-columns)

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to understand that code and modified it but end up with error. ORA-06550: line 8. Not sure if its that SQL Fiddle because i cant get to my DB until monday.I will try it then.