# How to combine multiple rows into one, based on event id, datetime, and an action into their own columns?

Tags: t-sql, pivot

I'm not sure how to word the topic title...

I have a table with data similar to below, where each row stores an event associated with alarms. For example, events might include:

- alarm goes active
- alarm clears/inactive
- alarm is acknowledged by an operator

Each group of events is associated with a single `eventid`.

I want to combine all events for each group of the same `eventid` into a single row, using the `eventtime` as the value for each of the alarm events/actions: active, cleared, and acked.

source data:

| eventid | eventtime | action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0203cfd5-3b82-4285-a830-447e8d5a63f7 | 2022-09-26 14:38:17.580 | Cleared |
| eb5f5fa5-a1ef-4aa7-b412-779676e72b3b | 2022-09-26 14:38:17.560 | Active |
| eb5f5fa5-a1ef-4aa7-b412-779676e72b3b | 2022-09-28 13:54:59.807 | Ack |
| eb5f5fa5-a1ef-4aa7-b412-779676e72b3b | 2022-09-28 13:55:55.437 | Cleared |

expected return:

| eventid | active | cleared | acked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0203cfd5-3b82-4285-a830-447e8d5a63f7 | null | 2022-09-26 14:38:18 | null |
| eb5f5fa5-a1ef-4aa7-b412-779676e72b3b | 2022-09-26 14:38:18 | 2022-09-28 13:55:55 | 2022-09-28 13:55:00 |

E.g.
[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: This is a PIVOT. T-SQL have this built-in. There are user code implementations too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pivot rows into multiple columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30119/pivot-rows-into-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pivot` or a combination of `MAX` + `CASE`

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([eventid] varchar(36), [eventtime] datetime, [action] varchar(7))
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    ([eventid], [eventtime], [action])
VALUES
    ('0203cfd5-3b82-4285-a830-447e8d5a63f7', '2022-09-26 14:38:17', 'Cleared'),
    ('eb5f5fa5-a1ef-4aa7-b412-779676e72b3b', '2022-09-26 14:38:17', 'Active'),
    ('eb5f5fa5-a1ef-4aa7-b412-779676e72b3b', '2022-09-28 13:54:59', 'Ack'),
    ('eb5f5fa5-a1ef-4aa7-b412-779676e72b3b', '2022-09-28 13:55:55', 'Cleared');
```

`pivot` version

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 AS t
PIVOT(
  MAX(EventTime) 
  FOR Action IN ([Active],[Cleared],[Ack])
) as p;
```

output:

[image]

`Max + Case` version

```
SELECT EventID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Action = 'Active' THEN EventTime ELSE NULL END) as [Active],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Action = 'Cleared' THEN EventTime ELSE NULL END) as [Cleared],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Action = 'Ack' THEN EventTime ELSE NULL END) as [Ack]
FROM Table1 as t
GROUP BY EventID;
```

output:

[image]

dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/IscYP2Ug)

Comment: That's awesome, I was hoping it'd be a simple PIVOT and it was :) I just haven't used it much before. Thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome!